# Regex Python with order for OR | pattern

Tags: python, regex

How can I return an ordered list from a regex?  Still kind of learning regex.

For example, lets say I have list = [a,b,c,c,b,a,g] and I want to have all the b's first, followed by the a's, then lastly a's in the list.  How can I regex for it?

I was thinking:
pattern = re.compile('b|c|a')
[letter for letter in list if pattern.match(letter)]

but this just comes out ['a','b','c','c','b','a']

What I want is ['b','b','c','c','a','a']

how would that be possible?  Thanks!

Comment: sorting is really not regular expression's attention, why not just sort your result in python?

Comment: Before someone invariably comes up with an esoteric method to do this using regex, you should first be asking if regex is the tool you want to be using for this job. (Hint: no)

Comment: I think you should use a sort algorithm and not a regex: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted look at the cmp argument of this function

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are for dealing with patterns in text, all they really do is search for and extract substrings from a string. What you want is to actual do intelligent processing. This is well outside the scope of a regex put quite easy in python :)

You make it sound like there should only be 'a', 'b', or 'c' in your list so you can write a simple comparison function

```
def cmp(c):
    return {'a' : 1, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 2}[c]
```

then give that to `sorted`

```
sorted(your_list, key=cmp)
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `regex` the way to approch this is to use `sorted` and write your own [custom comparator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_cmp.htm) function. example -

```
>>> def my_compare(x, y):
        return x - y
>>> sorted([5, 2, 4, 1, 3], cmp=my_compare)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So in your case, you would need to change the `my_compare` function to do ordered sort. I am not going to write that function for you, but doing this way would solve your problem.